# How to write data into hdfs using flink without termination?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am using the flink and am trying to store the data to HDFS.
The scenario is that firstly the data is coming from the kafka.
And then, flink receives the data from kafka and then write the data into hdfs. However, I can only identify the data in hdfs when I terminated the flink application.
What I want to do is to identify the data without terminating the flink application.

Below is my flink code. It is very straightforward. 
Is there any configuration so that I can store the data into hdfs based on the time slot without terminating the flink app?

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSink;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.DateTimeBucketer;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.RollingSink;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.SequenceFileWriter;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.StringWriter;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer09;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

import java.util.Properties;
public class ReadFromKafka {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // create execution environment
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    properties.setProperty("group.id", "flink_consumer");


    DataStream<String> stream = env
            .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<>("flink-demo", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties));

    DataStream<String> output = stream.map(new MapFunction<String, String>() {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = -6867736771747690202L;

      @Override
      public String map(String value) throws Exception {
        return "Stream Value: " + value;
      }
    });

    RollingSink sink = new RollingSink<String>("/user/sclee/flink/stream");
    sink.setBucketer(new DateTimeBucketer("yyyy-MM-dd--HHmm"));
    sink.setWriter(new StringWriter());
    sink.setBatchSize(1024 * 1024 * 400); // this is 400 MB,
    output.addSink(sink);

    env.execute();
  }


}
```

Comment: Any reason you chose to write Flink code? You could use Kafka HDFS Connect instead, which is ensured to be continuously running.

Comment: @cricket_007 I am using flink to process data before storing hdfs.

Comment: Sure, but some people like writing back into Kafka, rather than dumping directly to HDFS. That way, other processes can use that cleaned data when consuming from Kafka. And if you did that, then you could use Kafka Connect (which is code already written, all you need to do is write one config file)... But if you didn't want that, how long are you waiting for data to be in HDFS? How much data is in Kafka? Does the Flink UI show any progress being made while the app is running?

Comment: have you tried setting checkpointing via `env.enableCheckpointing(int)`? some sink implementations never write without a checkpoint